# Debugging using MavensMate (Sublime Text) in APEX code

Tags: apex, mavensmate

Is there a way you can do debug the apex code using MavensMate Sublime text? Anybody tried?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at mavens documentation .They provide ability to get debug log

http://mavensmate.com/Plugins/Sublime_Text/Debugging

QUICK LOG SETUP

> The "quick log" functionality allows you to create trace flags based on settings defined in your project's config/.debug configuration.

**Select MavensMate > Debug > New Quick Log or control + shift + L**

```
{
"levels": {
    "Workflow": "INFO", 
    "Callout": "INFO", 
    "System": "DEBUG", 
    "Database": "INFO", 
    "ApexCode": "DEBUG", 
    "Validation": "INFO", 
    "Visualforce": "DEBUG"
}, 
"users": [
    "005b0000000ThFMAB0" //array of user ids
], 
"expiration": 60 //in minutes
}
```

> TO CREATE A NEW TRACE FLAG TO GENERATE DEBUG LOGS, YOU CAN EITHER:

1. Use the Trace Flag UI
2. Create trace flag(s) based on configuration in your project's
       config/.debug file.

Comment: have you used this debugging successfully in MM? coping from the site is not really helped me and watch this video how you can do debugging in eclipse IDE and I was looking something like that... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1FXLz0BkUo

Comment: you mean you want to add breakpoints ?

Comment: yes something more interactive like in the video showed and I have recently started using MM and dunno much about still learning..

Comment: alright gono work on video to make your life easier .It will take some time probably this weekend to install on my machine .I pointed you to doc and if you need more info then its gono take time for me to get the video up .

Comment: Is interactive debugging enabled in your org ? To use breakpoint it should be first enabled in Org.

Comment: Interactive debugging in the [Eclipse] Force.com IDE is a premium feature, and I don't believe it's out of pilot yet. Thought that video is for BrainEngine, a 3rd party IDE for Salesforce.  I haven't looked at BrainEngine in quite a while. Their debugging features looked pretty cool, but I believe these are all technically available in the Developer Console if that actually worked. I haven't tried setting checkpoints in MM to generate logs, but the feature is there under the MavensMate->Debugging menu. I have successfully used MM with trace flags and log retrieval though.